# python subprocess.check_output giving wrong output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have problem execute this code here

```
subprocess.check_output(['ps -ef | grep ftp | wc -l'],env=environ,shell=True)
```

When I execute from terminal

```
ps -ef | grep ftp | wc -l
```

I get "1" as output which is fine.

Now, I execute same code from my python files as subprocess.check_output and it gives me 2. That is strange. Any Ideas why is it happening. Here is the complete code:

```
 def countFunction():
    environ = dict(os.environ)
    return subprocess.check_output(['ps -ef | grep ftp | wc -l'],env=environ,shell=True)

 count = countFunction()     
 print count
```

EDIT:
Just to update , I do not have any ftp connections on.So command line is printing 1 on command which is fine.
Thanks
Arvind

Comment: Does your python process have the name `ftp` in it by any chance?

Comment: No, just the above code. No ftp text in the process executed

Comment: You can fix this easily by simply running `ps -ef | grep ftp` and finding where the extra process is coming from.

Comment: Hint: `ps -ef | grep ftp` might, depending on timing, find not only `ftp`, but also `grep ftp`...

Comment: @twalberg:  *Both* processes are created before they run.  Otherwise there would be no way to connect their pipes.

Comment: @wallyk I don't believe that's universally true, although I have not surveyed all current implementations out there. It is entirely possible to 1) create the pipe structures, 2) create the first process which runs to completion, except the stdout write is buffered in a pipe that has no reader yet, 3) create the second process, which finds input to read on its input channel and processes it, but because the first process (`ps`) completed before the second process was set up, the second process is not in the output... I seem to remember that was a viable scenario at some point in the past...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `grep` command will find itself:

```
$ ps -ef | grep ftp
wallyk  12546 12326  0 16:25 pts/3    00:00:00 grep ftp
```

If you don't want that, exclude the grep command:

```
$ ps -ef | grep ftp | grep -v ftp
$
```

It would be better to drop the `-f` switch to `ps` so that the command line arguments are not searched.  That way, it won't find the `grep ftp` running:

```
$ ps -e | grep ftp | wc -l
```

Comment: He doesn't have any FTP processes running, so he wants it to return only 1.

Comment: Thanks for your reply wallyk . Yes but with python code , your above command does not print anything, even if ftp is on.

Comment: @MartinKonecny:  Exactly!  By excluding the `grep` command from the results, only other processes with `ftp` in their arguments will count.

Comment: Thank you wallyk, -f flag was causing problem. Cheers!

Comment: @wallyk any ideas why output of ps -e | grep ftp | wc -l shows 1 in command line output  while 2 form python code!

Comment: @wallyk Another way you will see commonly to avoid the second `grep` would be `ps -ef | grep [f]tp` - that will match `ftp` but not `[f]tp`...

Comment: @89n3ur0n:  All that comes to mind is that python sets up the parameters differently.  It should be easy to check by examining the output python captures from `ps -ef`.